# Gutenberg Reusable Block as part of WordPress Theme page

Tags: theme-development, block-editor

I'm using WordPress "Twenty Nineteen" (child) theme. What I'm trying to achieve is to include one of my previously created Gutenberg Reusable Blocks as part of theme's `index.php` file.

The reason for that is to be able to quickly and easily edit what's displayed at the begginig of the homepage, right above the list of entries/posts.

In other words: is it possible to include previously created Gutenberg Reusable Block in php?

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. I hope you find the answer(s) you are looking for. Our site is different from most - if you have not done so yet, consider checking out the [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to find out how things work.